How to prevent STM32CubeIDE (Eclipse) from creating workspace dir after I delete it
On Windows, trying to delete some (about 5) old workspaces from STM32CubeIDE -- which basically is Eclipse. I deleted the workspace dirs, but the IDE re-creates them each time I launch it. I close the IDE, delete the dirs then launch the IDE. Then all the dirs are back. The dirs each have a .metadata dir which contains a .ide.log file.
I know how to remove the workspaces from the recently opened list. That doesn't help. The IDE still recreates the dirs.
This could be an eclipse issue or maybe specific to STM32CubeIDE.
Clearly, the workspace dir paths are stored somewhere, but where?? Searched all files in the app install dir C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2\STM32CubeIDE, but didn't find the path info. Where else could it be?
I found this: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubeide-mcus/cubeide-keeps-creating-old-workspace-folder/td-p/95367 which says "I managed to fix this problem, by deleting config files in new workspace folder, so far old workspace folder not being created again", but what does that mean? what config files? new workspace? I posted a request to clarify in January, but no reply :(
According to How to delete a workspace in Eclipse?, deleting the workspace is simply deleting its dir ... but no mention about the dir getting recreated.
I found this: Eclipse: fully remove an old project? but that for removing a project from a workspace; not removing a workspace.
Here's the directory structure. Well, of course there are many other directories around these. This shows the ones of interest and their common ancestor.
code\
-TQ\
--ide-workspace\ (the real workspace dir)
---.metadata\
---.settings\
---.project
---firmware\ (my project dir)
----.project (and all my project files)
-WR\
--three\ (rogue workspace dir)
---.metadata\ (only subdir)
----.ide.log (only file)

FYI, .ide.log is too long to include here, but here's the top:
2024-11-12 09:53:23,940 [INFO] Activator:176 - 
2024-11-12 09:53:23,945 [INFO] Activator:177 - !SESSION log4j initialized
2024-11-12 09:53:28,612 [INFO] LogOutputStream:77 - [STDOUT_REDIRECT] 
2024-11-12 09:53:31,728 [INFO] ApplicationProperties:184 - Using Application install path: C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.common.mx_6.11.1.202404110753
2024-11-12 09:53:31,745 [INFO] DbMcusXml:78 - Set database path to: C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.common.mx_6.11.1.202404110753\\db\/mcu/
2024-11-12 09:53:31,745 [INFO] ApiDb:274 - Set plugin database path to: C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.common.mx_6.11.1.202404110753\\db\/plugins/boardmanager/
...


One instance of Eclipse uses only one workspace directory with a .metadata sub-directory. Look at the time stamps when the file(s) .metadata/.log was/were created. Do they match with the time you launched Eclipse? Maybe a different tool synchronizes/restores these directories.

@howlger The files in the workspaces that get re-created do have a timestamp matching the time when I launch the IDE. Launching the IDE results in creating the files&dirs.

If several workspaces are created, several instances are run, which can also be headless instances. How many workspaces exactly and in which directories are the workspaces created? Are the same number of directories created when all projects in the STM32CubeIDE are closed? What files are created in each workspace? Are exactly the same files created in each workspace? Do all workspaces contain a .metadata/.log file and if yes, do they differ?

I did delete all but one project from my workspace. Today, I see only one other/extra workspace created when I open the one I intend. The one I don't want is one directory level higher. It's the one I described; contains a dir .metadata which contains a file .ide.log which has 376 lines of log info. If I close the project in my workspace, close the IDE, delete the rogue workspace dir, then start the IDE, the rogue workspace is created again.

Please tell the exact directory structure. The Eclipse platform creates a .log, but not an .ide.log file. Maybe it is STM32CubeIDE specific. Please share the content of the .ide.log file.

I included the directory structure and some of .ide.log above. There is no .log. Based on your input, I am starting to think the issue is STM32CubeIDE specific.

I also think it's a STM32CubeIDE specific issue. The .metadata subdirectory and the .project file should not be contained in the same directory. If /code/TQ/ide-workspace is your Eclipse workspace, then the projects should be in separate directories inside or outside the workspace. Inside the workspace, a project directory containing the .project file is something like /code/TQ/ide-workspace/my_project (you can also have nested projects). In contrast to the .metadata subdirectory, the project directories are intended to be shared.

I deleted code/TQ/ide-workspace/.project. But, rogue workspace dir still gets created same as alway. also, I added more detail above about the dir structure.

In Eclipse, when you right-click the project (currently you have one project only, right?) and choose Properties what location is shown in Resource?

code\TQ\ide-workspace\firmware ... which is what I expect. and yes only one project

code\TQ\ide-workspace\firmware looks fine. You might look into code\TQ\ide-workspace\.project to get the name of the project that has been created directly in the workspace directory instead of in a subdirectory. But this seems not the main issue. In Window > Preferences are there STM32CubeIDE specific settings where the code\WR directory is set?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
